# How can a connected TCP socket send/receive multiple files simultaneously?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sockets, network-programming

Basically I got a listener that (when it receives a new connection) creates a new socketWorker and assigns the connection to the client to it.
Now if the client sends a huge file(that takes, say 30 seconds to be fully received) and afterwards sends a tiny file of a few bytes the tiny file isn't received until the huge file has been fully received.
This is obviously a bad approach and I wonder how I could do it so the files would be sent simultaneously?

As of now I'm using async methods, every time a file has been fully received BeginReceive() is called again to receive the next file (bad way).

Any way to fix this?
I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to implement multiplexing, like for example [SPDY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPDY) does. This is (basically) done by framing message parts and supplying a stream ID on each frame. This way, multiple streams can be exchanged over a single connection.

Alternatively, you could open one connection per file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. SPDY seems a tad complicated so I guess I'll go with opening a connection for each file.
When you say I should open a connection for each file; should I listen to multiple ports or how exactly would this be done in practice?

Comment: @user1876706 I'm not saying you should implement SPDY, but you can use the same idea. But your client can also just open multiple connections to the same port, like HTTP does. One request per file, one file per request. It all depends on your current protocol.

Comment: Ahh I see.
In regards to a client opening multiple connections on one port:
Can I just copy the already connected socket to a new socket and use that? Or should I literally make a new connection for every new file?

Comment: @user1876706 No and yes respectively.